# Anaconda 5.2 stops working without any reason

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I was using python 3.6.8 verison of Anaconda for tensorflow when all of a sudden it crashed and later too.

I reinstalled it but to no avail.

Need help?

Comment: This is not enough information to possibly debug the issue! At the very least post logs from the crash.

Comment: there were no logs. it stopped working the same way other apps do in windows 10